# Firebase notification works in background but doesn't appear in Foreground in Oreo

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to make push notification using Firebase to my app. I tried it and it works perfectly in the background in Oreo, but when I try to open the app and send a notification from another account, the notification does not appear.

How do I solve this and where is the problem in my code?

This is part of the code of my service:

```
 public class FirebaseMessagingService extends 
     com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService {

     @Override
     public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
         super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
         String messageTitle = remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle();
         String messageBody = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();

         NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                this, getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_id))
             .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
             .setContentTitle(messageTitle)
             .setContentText(messageBody);
        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, MainAdsActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                this, 0, resultIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        int id = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();

        builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        startForeground(id,builder.build());

        NotificationManager notificationManager = 
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(id, builder.build());

     }
 }
```

Android manifest file:

```
  <service
        android:name=".FirebaseMessagingService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
        android:value="@string/default_notification_channel_id"/>
```

Cloud functions

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin=require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
const api = admin.firestore()
api.settings({timestampsInSnapshots: true})
 exports.fuync=functions
.firestore.document("Users/{userid}/notification/{notification_id}")
.onWrite((change,context)=>{
const userid=context.params.userid;
const notification_id=context.params.notification_id;
return admin.firestore().collection('Users')





    .doc(userid).collection('notification')
    .doc(notification_id).get().then(queryRes
    ult=>{

    const fromuserid=queryResult.data().from;
    const frommessage=queryResult.data().message;

    const 
    fromdata=admin.firestore()
     .collection('Users').doc(fromuserid).get();
    const todata=admin.firestore()
     .collection('Users').doc(userid).get();

    return Promise.all([fromdata,todata]).then(result=>{
        const fromname=result[0].data().name;
        const toname=result[1].data().name;
        const tokenid=result[1].data().token_id;
       //return console.log("from :" +fromname + "TO: " +toname);

       const payload= {
           notification: {
               title : "notification from" +fromname,
               body : frommessage,
               icon : "default"
           }
       };
       return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokenid,payload).then(result=>{
           return console.log("NOTIFICATION SENT.");
       });
    });

});
 });
```

build gradle

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 27
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.amr.app"
    minSdkVersion 18
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner 

buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the solution I have done and works perfectly in foreground and background for Oreo version and higher versions.

Creating a notification channel is very crucial. The most important thing is the String id inside `NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel()`.
it must be the one provided by firebase which is : `default_notification_channel_id`

and the code will be like this:

```
    private static final CharSequence NAME = "amro";

 @Override
 public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
 super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
 //____ID _____
 int id = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
 //_____NOTIFICATION ID'S FROM FCF_____
 String messageTitle = remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle();
 String messageBody = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();

 NotificationCompat.Builder builder =
     new NotificationCompat
    .Builder(this, getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_id))
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
    .setContentTitle(messageTitle)
    .setContentText(messageBody);

 //_____REDIRECTING PAGE WHEN NOTIFICATION CLICKS_____
 Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, ProfileActivity.class);
 PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent
     .getActivity(this, 0, resultIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
     );
 builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

 if ( Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O ) {

      int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;
      String channelID = BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID;
      NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel
     (getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_id), BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID, importance);
      channel.setDescription(channelID);
      NotificationManager notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
      //assert notificationManager != null;
      notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
 }


 NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
 assert notificationManager != null;
 notificationManager.notify(id, builder.build());


 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Since android oreo there is Channel

> When you target Android 8.0 (API level 26), you must implement one or more notification channels. If your targetSdkVersion is set to 25 or lower, when your app runs on Android 8.0 (API level 26) or higher, it behaves the same as it would on devices running Android 7.1 (API level 25) or lower.

try to using support library 26 or later and check this [Create and Manage Notification Channels](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/channels)

try to use this method to create `NotificationCompat.Builder`

```
public NotificationCompat.Builder initChannels() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 26) {
        return new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
    }
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    String id = BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID;
    NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(id, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
    channel.setDescription(BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID);
    notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    return new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, id);
}
```

the create new instance from this method

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = initChannels();
```

Comment: I have added my SDK version can you check it?

Comment: it is right to add a channel and this helps me . I have posted my answer and it works . can you check it ?

Answer (score 0):

```
String messageTitle = remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle();
 String messageBody = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();
```

try

```
String messageTitle = remoteMessage.getData().getTitle();
 String messageBody = remoteMessage.getData().getBody();
```

Comment: it can't be applied, as i dont use data object in my cloud functions

Answer (score 0):

First add logs in onMessageArrived()

Log.d("Firebase PM service", "onMessageArrived called");

and check if you are getting this log in LogCat.

If you don't, then something is not working properly on Firebase end.

If you are receiving it, then it means you are doing something wrong after getting push msg(i.e. not displaying notification properly). Also check LogCat whether any exception is thrown or not.

Then post your replay.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code in FirebaseMessagingService.

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
  super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
  String messageTitle = remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle();
  String messageBody = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();

  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    CharSequence name = “Your channel name, It will be visible in app setting”;
    String description =“Description for your channel”;
    int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;
    NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(SOME_CHANNEL_ID, name, importance);
    channel.setDescription(description);
    NotificationManager notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
    notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
  }

  NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat
               .Builder(this, getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_id))
               .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
               .setContentTitle(messageTitle)
               .setContentText(messageBody);
  Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, MainAdsActivity.class);
  PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent
 .getActivity(this, 0, resultIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
 );
  int id = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
  builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
  startForeground(id,builder.build());

  NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
  notificationManager.notify(id, builder.build());

 }
}
```

Comment: not working , I have posted my answer and it works , there was a little problem in your solution.